# XSD all-or-nothing group

Tags: xsd

I want to match these two documents:

```
<a>
  <b/>
</a>
```

and:

```
<a>
  <b/>
  <c/>
  <d/>
</a>
```

That is, there must be either neither of `c` and `d` or both of `c` and `d`.

I've tried to have a `choice` of two `sequences`, but I get: "The content model is
not determinist.", I guess because the choice has to be disambiguated on the
first element, which is the same for the two different documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put `c` and `d` inside a sequence group with minOccurs=0. Like this:

```
<element name="a">
  <complexType>
    <sequence>
      <element name="b" />
      <sequence minOccurs="0">
        <element name="c" />
        <element name="d" />
      </sequence>
    </sequence>
  </complexType>
</element>
```

If you want `c` and `d` to be able to appear in any order, you can do this:

```
<element name="a">
  <complexType>
    <sequence>
      <element name="b" />
      <choice minOccurs="0">
        <sequence>
          <element name="c" />
          <element name="d" />
        </sequence>
        <sequence>
          <element name="d" />
          <element name="c" />
        </sequence>
      </choice>
    </sequence>
  </complexType>
</element>
```

Obviously, this approach does not scale well if you have more than two members in the group.

Comment: Is there any way to do it that will allow the elements to occur in any order?